# How to retrieve sql text of cursor?

Tags: oracle, database-cursor

If I have a cursor and would like to log the text of the cursor during execution is it possible to use the cursor name in some way and retrieve the SQL?

For example,

```
OPEN cursor_1 for 
    SELECT ...
```

I'd like to believe I can do something like `cursor_1%NAME` much like I can use the other attributes of a cursor. ([%ISOPEN, %FOUND](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems011.htm), etc.).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no way of linking a cursor *name* to it's SQL text being parsed, but joining `V$open_cursor` with `v$sql` using `SQL_ID`, you should be able to pull out & log the details of the SQL statement being logged for those cursors which are open.

```
SELECT sql_id,
       user_name,
       sid,
       saddrsql_fulltext
FROM   v$sql
       join v$open_cursor USING (sql_id)
```

Perhaps you could correlate the SQL text with cursor, but that's going to have to be a manual process

Comment: Thanks much for your response.  I was trying to use DISPLAY_CURSOR in much the same way but was having mixed results.  In any case it seems to be more difficult than I thought it would be.  Thanks for your time.